# Capture repeating group with RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse an input line looking like this:

> AC#10,N850FD,10%,WEEK,IFR,1/22:45,2/00:58,390,F,0743,KEWR,3/02:30,3/05:04,380,F,1202,KMEM,3/11:15,3/20:04,350,F,0038,LFPG,4/04:00,4/15:35,330,F,5342,ZGGG,4/19:05,4/22:50,370,F,5608,RJAA,5/13:25,5/14:45,300,F,0060,RJBB,5/18:05,6/06:35,330,F,0060,KMEM,6/20:45,0/05:42,340,F,0948,PHNL,0/07:21,0/12:24,370,F,0802,KLAX,0/14:49,0/18:09,370,F,0806,KMEM

The first 5 "fields" are the "header" ("AC#10,N850FD,10%,WEEK,IFR"), and the rest is are repeating groups  of 6 "fields" (e.g. "1/22:45,2/00:58,390,F,0743,KEWR").

I'm a RegEx newbie, but to do this I have come up with the following RegEx statement: `(AC#)(\d+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+),(\d+%),(WEEK|DAY),(IFR|VFR)(,\d\/\d{2}:\d{2},\d\/\d{2}:\d{2},\d+,[FR],\d+,[A-Z0-9]{3,5})+`.

The result of the first many groups (each "field" in the "header") are extracted fine, and I can easily access each value (group). However my problem is the following/repeating groups. Only the last of the repeating "groups" are extracted.  If I remove the very last "+" only the first of the repeating "groups" are extracted (naturally).

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/HsQMge/1

Here is the result I hope to get (as groups):

- AC#
- 10
- N850FD
- 10%
- WEEK
- IFR
- ,1/22:45,2/00:58,390,F,0743,KEWR
- ,3/02:30,3/05:04,380,F,1202,KMEM
- ,3/11:15,3/20:04,350,F,0038,LFPG
- ,4/04:00,4/15:35,330,F,5342,ZGGG
- ,4/19:05,4/22:50,370,F,5608,RJAA
- ,5/13:25,5/14:45,300,F,0060,RJBB
- ,5/18:05,6/06:35,330,F,0060,KMEM
- ,6/20:45,0/05:42,340,F,0948,PHNL
- ,0/07:21,0/12:24,370,F,0802,KLAX
- ,0/14:49,0/18:09,370,F,0806,KMEM

Comment: Where do the groups begin/end?

Comment: The first of the reeating groups begin after "(IFR|VFR)" and ends with "KEWR". As in the example (except I forgot to include the last "field"): "1/22:45,2/00:58,390,F,0743,KEWR".

Comment: I got wild idea. How about a split on the comma to get an array. Then join the first 5 elements of that array. And then join every next group of 6 elements to get the data.

Comment: LukStorms I am sure that will work to extract the data, but at the same time I would like to use the RegEx to "validate" the data

Answer (score 2):

Probably RegEx is not the right tool to do this task. Maybe you can use it just for splitting string into array. Rest job is for `array_chunk` :

```
$str = "AC#10,N850FD,10%,WEEK,IFR,1/22:45,2/00:58,390,F,0743,KEWR,3/02:30,3/05:04,380,F,1202,KMEM,3/11:15,3/20:04,350,F,0038,LFPG,4/04:00,4/15:35,330,F,5342,ZGGG,4/19:05,4/22:50,370,F,5608,RJAA,5/13:25,5/14:45,300,F,0060,RJBB,5/18:05,6/06:35,330,F,0060,KMEM,6/20:45,0/05:42,340,F,0948,PHNL,0/07:21,0/12:24,370,F,0802,KLAX,0/14:49,0/18:09,370,F,0806,KMEM";

$data = preg_split('/[,#]/',$str);
$data = array_chunk($data, 6);

var_dump($data);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZFrSwJBFIa/@ytECw0OzJmrs2Mla@1aeUH8YhQhS0ZGF5ZVg379ds4Y@emF9zmXd86Um7Kuzwflpmw0Tra7qnnRbKVXbYkw8xbza5B4CsssG8NtvgAplArGghKIwXrQCUIO2DMaxtlyAVqgChpZbUAD2jOXChWMp9mUfCmDtKQKI7exH7WHST4fgRFoAiKptEFTnWZutVHwMBoxl0lAS0o5qFf3InfoYXGXpmCF1EFZVsM5NR7mOyQ@HLLvud8JdMf5kcd8jnNRH3J@WqpN5InxML@ZTdjvBSVJpQrK/O1Hz@@bpPfs096ElfYkR@7i/FafjrwudgVduaxeXlfb8uNt1@2IR2g/iQ7wB5z1/0uKqip@Vs@b/dd7N3rQdIQb30W1Wu8/y4PJzuCyrn8B)

Comment: C# is my poison, but I understand what you are saying. I could comma-separate the entire line, then concat the sections, and then use RegEx to validate each section. But believe it should be possible with RegEx in one go some how

Comment: @PelleLiljendal In a way you almost have a validation. Just put a start of line `^` in front of your regex, repeat the data part, and then add an end of line `$` at the end of your regex.  If 1 of the data groups doesn't comply that regex wouldn't have a match?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it to work with one regular expression (still think it should be possible), however I got it working in two passes. First I use the following RegEx, to split the individual fields of the "header" into groups, and then grab the rest of the input line as the last group (using "(.*)" after the last comma):

`(AC#)(\d+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+),(\d+%),(WEEK|DAY),(IFR|VFR),(.*)`

This leaves me with the rest of  the information in one single group ("1/22:45,2/00:58,390,F,0743,KEWR,3/02:30,3/05:04,380,F,1202,KMEM,3/11:15,3/20:04,350,F,0038,LFPG,4/04:00,4/15:35,330,F,5342,ZGGG,4/19:05,4/22:50,370,F,5608,RJAA,5/13:25,5/14:45,300,F,0060,RJBB,5/18:05,6/06:35,330,F,0060,KMEM,6/20:45,0/05:42,340,F,0948,PHNL,0/07:21,0/12:24,370,F,0802,KLAX,0/14:49,0/18:09,370,F,0806,KMEM"). I then parse this group with another regular expression, that groups the repeating sections (without a problem - now there is no longer a "header"):

`(\d\/\d{2}:\d{2},\d\/\d{2}:\d{2},\d+,[FR],\d+,[A-Z0-9]{3,4})+`

The groups are as I had hoped (even better as "," is no longer part of the result). Odd its no working with the "header". Anyhow I don't have to resort to "manually" splitting the line, and the RegEx statements can still "validate" each section.